# Error when trying process .json files to pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to merge various .json files so I can later run sentiment analysis on them.
I tried already other approaches but they always end up with an error.
I checked whether the .json is correctly formatted and can't find any issues there. I also attached an example of a .json file.

Error message is attached below my code.

```
import glob
import json

# list all files containing News from Guardian API
files = list(glob.iglob('/Users/xxx/tempdata/articles_data/*.json'))

news_data = []
for file in files:
    
    news_file = open(file, "r", encoding = 'utf-8')

    # Read in news and store in list: news_data
    for line in news_file:
        news = json.loads(line)
        news_data.append(news)

    news_file.close()
```

**Updated Error Output**

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-3019ee85b15b> in <module>
     12     # Read in news and store in list: news_data
     13     for line in news_file:
---> 14         news = json.load(line)
     15         news_data.append(news)
     16 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    291     kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
    292     """
--> 293     return loads(fp.read(),
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

**2019-11-01.json**

```
{
     "id":"business/2019/nov/01/google-snaps-up-fitbit-for-21bn",
     "type":"article",
     "sectionId":"business",
     "sectionName":"Business",
     "webPublicationDate":"2019-11-01T14:26:19Z",
     "webTitle":"Google snaps up Fitbit for $2.1bn",
     "webUrl":"https://www.theguardian.com/business/2019/nov/01/google-snaps-up-fitbit-for-21bn",
     "apiUrl":"https://content.guardianapis.com/business/2019/nov/01/google-snaps-up-fitbit-for-21bn",
     "fields":{
        "headline":"Google snaps up Fitbit for $2.1bn",
        "standfirst":"<p>Takeover allows web giant to take on Apple in fast-growing smartwatch and wearables business</p>",
        "trailText":"Takeover allows web giant to take on Apple in fast-growing smartwatch and wearables business",
        "byline":"Kalyeena Makortoff",
        "main":"<figure class=\"element element-image\" data-media-id=\"fc8abb0f70105fcab3aee86dea6c89e211337660\"> <img src=\"https://media.guim.co.uk/fc8abb0f70105fcab3aee86dea6c89e211337660/0_158_3571_2143/1000.jpg\" alt=\"The wireless activity tracker Zip by Fitbit Inc\" width=\"1000\" height=\"600\" class=\"gu-image\" /> <figcaption> <span class=\"element-image__caption\">The wireless activity tracker Zip by Fitbit Inc. Google has confirmed it will buy Fitbit for $2.1bn.</span> <span class=\"element-image__credit\">Photograph: Franck Robichon/EPA</span> </figcaption> </figure>",
        "body":"<p>Google has snapped up the Fitbit... ",
        "newspaperPageNumber":"38",
        "wordcount":"679",
        "firstPublicationDate":"2019-11-01T14:25:58Z",
        "isInappropriateForSponsorship":"false",
        "isPremoderated":"false",
        "lastModified":"2019-11-01T18:56:38Z",
        "newspaperEditionDate":"2019-11-02T00:00:00Z",
        "productionOffice":"UK",
        "publication":"The Guardian",
        "shortUrl":"https://gu.com/p/cjeze",
        "shouldHideAdverts":"false",
        "showInRelatedContent":"true",
        "thumbnail":"https://media.guim.co.uk/fc8abb0f70105fcab3aee86dea6c89e211337660/0_158_3571_2143/500.jpg",
        "legallySensitive":"false",
        "lang":"en",
        "isLive":"true",
        "bodyText":"Google has snapped up the Fitbit activity tracker business in a $2.1bn (\u00a31.6bn) deal that will enable the search giant to go toe-to-toe with Apple in the fast-growing smartwatch and wearables business..." ,
        "charCount":"4149",
        "shouldHideReaderRevenue":"false",
        "showAffiliateLinks":"false",
        "bylineHtml":"<a href=\"profile/kalyeena-makortoff\">Kalyeena Makortoff</a>"
     },
     "isHosted":false,
     "pillarId":"pillar/news",
     "pillarName":"News"
  },
```

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `sentiment-analysis` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading json from file, you should use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`. `json.loads` is for reading JSON from string. See json.load [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).

For example:

```
import json

with open('ts.json', 'r') as f:
    content = json.load(f)

print(content)
```